# How to solve 403 Forbidden error of loading script file (zend Framework 2)

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework2

When I try access my project in online server some javaScript dors not load and return 403 forbidden error. The script is loaded using `$this->appendHeadScript('path');` function in zend Framework 2. It works nicely in local server. and some other scripts loaded through this function is loaded properly.

can you resolve this?

Comment: check capital letters in your script file path.

Comment: This looks like a file permissions issue, check the permissions of the folder and js file.